# Auto Build JSON file on saving Angular 4 CLI VISUAL STUDIO 2017

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017

Im a newbie to Angular 4. So recently started with VS 2017 with its builtin Angular support. Along with it, Im using NPM Task Runner to run NG BUILD along with project build.

But is there is any way to reflect the changes on JSON file after executing the project without NG BUILD command. Now for reflect the changes in JSON file I need to run **NG BUILD**.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `ng serve` you will get live reloading when you change any of your files. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That means when ever we save an HTML file or JSON file it gets automatically reflected on the application running?

Comment: Yes, it's fantastic. It can somtimes take a few seconds to recompile and refresh. You'll see output in the console as it's recompiling immediately after you save a file. There are some minor bugs as well, if you add or remove entire files sometimes it doesn't reload properly and you just need to kill it and restart ng serve manually. But it mostly works great.

Comment: Sorry am a little confused. In my package.json its already there. but still even after saving HTML or JSON its not reflecting.

This is the script portion of my package file
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "watch": "ng build --watch"
    },

Comment: Did you run 'ng serve'?

Comment: Sorry.. because of my less experience with Angular, do we need to run that separately if we specified it in Package.json? If we need to run it, which command to run first before executing the application.. Build or Serve?

Comment: Sorry my bad, `npm start` just runs `ng serve` in this case. What happens when you run `npm start`?

Comment: I tried and its automatically exectues NG SERVE. So a little more clarification if you dont mind.. So we need to execute NPM start before executing the application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160909/discussion-between-brendan-whiting-and-sforsandeep).